# add multiple users for .htaccess

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

I have protected my website with .htaccess file with one user, script that i use in below

.htaccess :

```
ErrorDocument 401 "Unauthorized Access"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
AuthType Basic
AuthName "domain-name.com"
AuthUserFile "/home/path/.htpasswds/domain-name/passwd"
require valid-user
```

passwd :

```
user1:password1
```

How to add multiple users? I have tried as below and not success.

```
user1:password1
user2:password2
```

Please assist me in this, thanks in advance

Comment: ker login fails

Answer (score 14):

First you need to create the htpasswd file in your home directory using the *[htpasswd](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/htpasswd.html)* command.
SSH into your directory and enter:

```
htpasswd -c .htpasswd userone
```

Enter password for *userone* twice.

For multiple users, repeat the command without the *-c*

```
htpasswd .htpasswd membertwo
```

Thats all.